# MVC Automapper update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i tried to update my database table some fields

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult Edit(MemberTasks membertaskdetails)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            MemberTasks Mtasks = db.MemberTask.Find(membertaskdetails.id);
            Mtasks.Taskid = membertaskdetails.Taskid;
            Mtasks.status = membertaskdetails.status;
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(membertaskdetails,Mtasks);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(membertaskdetails);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
 public class MemberTasks
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Task ID")]
    public int Taskid { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public int status { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Created By")]
    public string createdby { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Team Lead")]
    public string TeamLead { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Members")]
    public string Membersid { get; set; }

}
```

Code is executed successfully but the problem is remaining fields also updated with null value i have 6 columns i want to update 2 columns only.
Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

Your source and destination object used in AutoMapper are of the same type (`MemberTasks`). That's not how AutoMapper is supposed to be used. AutoMapper is used to map between domain models and view models.

So you must have a view model containing the properties passed from the view:

```
public class MemberTasksViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Taskid { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(MemberTasksViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MemberTasks domainModel = db.MemberTask.Find(viewModel.Id);
        Mapper.Map(viewModel, domainModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i tried but i got error                       Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
UpdateMemberTasks -> MemberTasks
TaskManager.Models.UpdateMemberTasks -> TaskManager.Models.MemberTasks

Destination path:
MemberTasks

Source value:
TaskManager.Models.UpdateMemberTasks

Comment: Yes, you need to define a mapping between your models first using the `Mapper.CreateMap` method.

Comment: Thanks i forget to update CreateMap once again thx for support. Now its working fine

Comment: @user1127905, if that post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work